# Android App crashes after changing minSdkVersion

Tags: android

I am an Android newbie and have been following Google's basic training courses online. In the beginning, the minSdkVersion was set to 8, but now I need to change it to use a Holo theme as such http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

The problem is that after I updated the minSdkVersion to 11 or 14, my app just keeps crashing....

I changed the minSdkVersion in build.gradle(Module:app).

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cindy.myfirstapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
 09-29 18:33:49.901  22164-22164/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cindy.myfirstapp, PID: 22164
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cindy.myfirstapp/com.example.cindy.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.cindy.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        

    

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: where is your crashing log???/

Comment: add your logat errors please

Comment: added the logcat errors

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.cindy.myfirstapp/com.example.cindy.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

The log says it all. Use `Theme.AppCompat` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: thank you!! I can only accept this answer after 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import in your android manifest this line ' android:theme="@style/AppTheme"':

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/hub_gcm_100"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ....

</application
```

And import correct dependences in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Tell me if I can helped you and good luck!!